# how to transpose data from csv file in d3.js

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I have a csv file with data as mentioned below:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---------+
| A | B | C | D | E | F | G | Episode |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---------+
| 3 | 1 | 5 | 0 | 2 | 6 | 0 | 1       |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---------+
```

Now I want to transpose it using d3.js so that my final output will be like below:

```
+----------+-------+---------+
| alphabet | value | Episode |
+----------+-------+---------+
| A        | 3     | 1       |
+----------+-------+---------+
| B        | 1     | 1       |
+----------+-------+---------+
| C        | 5     | 1       |
+----------+-------+---------+
| D        | 0     | 1       |
+----------+-------+---------+
| E        | 2     | 1       |
+----------+-------+---------+
| F        | 6     | 1       |
+----------+-------+---------+
| G        | 0     | 1       |
+----------+-------+---------+
```

How Can I do that?

So far- I did load the csv:

```
d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, Data){
                if(error){
                    throw error;
                }

                Data.forEach(function (d){
                     d.A = +d.A
                     .....
                     .....
             });
```

But how do I actually transpose it?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little bit misleading, because it seems that you want to generate a new CSV with the desired structure.

Actually, what you want is to have a data array with this structure:

```
[{
    alphabet: "A",
    value: 3,
    Episode: 1
}, {
    alphabet: "B",
    value: 1,
    Episode: 1
}, 
//etc...
];
```

You can create a new data array with this structure when you understand how `d3.csv` parses a CSV file: that first line will be the headers, and all the following rows are the values.

So, there are several ways to create a new data array, this is one of them:

```
var transposedData = [];

data.forEach(function(d) {
  for (var key in d) {
    var obj = {};
    if (key !== "Episode") {
      obj.alphabet = key;
      obj.value = d[key];
      obj.Episode = d.Episode;
      transposedData.push(obj)
    } 
  }
});
```

Here is a demo (I added another row with a 2nd episode, just for completeness):

```js
var csv = `A,B,C,D,E,F,G,Episode
3,1,5,0,2,6,0,1
2,4,3,5,7,9,6,2`;

var data = d3.csvParse(csv, function(d) {
  for (var key in d) {
    d[key] = +d[key];
  }
  return d;
});

var transposedData = [];

data.forEach(function(d) {
  for (var key in d) {
    var obj = {};
    if (key !== "Episode") {
      obj.alphabet = key;
      obj.value = d[key];
      obj.Episode = d.Episode;
      transposedData.push(obj)
    } 
  }
});

console.log(transposedData)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

The code below stores the original data in an array called `new_data`. It contains objects with the keys `'alphabet'`, `'value'` and `'Episode'`.

```
d3.csv("data.csv", function(data){
  new_data = []
  for (var property in data) {
    if (property != 'Episode') {
      new_data.push({'alphabet': property, 'value':parseInt(data[property]), 'Episode': 1})
    }
  } 
  console.log(new_data)
})
```

Here is how the `new_data` array looks like:
[image]

Comment: `data` is an array of objects, not an object. Also, I guess the Episode value should be determined dynamically instead of being hard-coded.

Comment: data is an object. `console.log(typeof data)` -> `object`. `console.log(data)` -> `Object { A: "3", B: "1", C: "5", D: "0", E: "2", F: "6", G: "0", Episode: "1" }`

Comment: This would only be correct if you were using D3 **v5** where the second argument to `d3.csv` can be the row conversion function. However, as OP uses `function(error, Data)` specifying two parameters, this indicates the use of v4 or lower, where the argument passed to the callback is an array of objects. Also, there is a `Data.forEach()` in OP's code.

Comment: Ah, good point, I didn't consider the difference between versions! I'm indeed using v5.